# Convert HTML Date to Mysql Format

Tags: javascript, mysql, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using a bootstrapdatetimepicker as well as moment.js

When i call the following

```
var starteventtime= ($('#startdatetime').data('DateTimePicker').date());
```

I get a date similar to

```
Wed Mar 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000
```

I also have the option for the user to save their own format of the date. So any code will have to take this into consideration.

```
<?php
   $datetimeformat = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm';
 ?>
    $(function() {
             $('#startdatetime').datetimepicker({
             format: '<?php echo $datetimeformat; ?>'
    });
```

How do i parse this on the client side with javascript to get Mysql formatted date so when the data is serialized it will be in a format ready for insertion into the database like below

```
2019-03-27 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite certain whatever the date time picker returns is a `Date` object and not a string (if it isn't, use another picker, because this one is useless).

When you have the `Date` object, you can format that however you want to insert it into your database. For example with the answer given here: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into converting your dates into a standard Unix timestamp. Its super easy in every environment you're working in (Mysql, php, javascript). For example, in javascript `Date.now()` returns the current time as a Unix timestamp. Look up how to do that for the other places you're working with time. With that as a standard, you can just pass around the timestamps for your dates without having to worry about formatting until you're ready to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice , i used

```
moment($('#startdatetime').data('DateTimePicker').date()).format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm"));
```

to convert it to an object that was in  mysql format.